# String Linked list returning null symbol

Tags: c

This is a program i've been working on, and posting about a lot lately sorry about that, and I've been progressing and running into bugs. This program lets you put strings into a linked list and then lets you manipulate the list. "ins" lets you insert strings into the list, "del" lets you delete those strings, and "prl" lets you review what's in the list. I think i've gotten a decent amount done, but when you run prl after "Command?," and also have items in the list, it shows up as the null symbol, when I want it to show up as my list of strings.

e.g.
Command? ins Hey
Command? ins Lol
Command? prl
Hey
Lol
Command? del Hey
Command? prl
Lol

and so on. I hope this is descriptive enough. Let me know if you have any input, Thank you very much!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN_LENGTH 4
#define MAX_LENGTH 11

struct node{
     char list;
      int count;
       struct node *next;
 };

typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node *ListNode;

void ins(ListNode *ptr, char value);
char del(ListNode *ptr, char value);
char prl(ListNode currPtr);


int main(void){

  ListNode startPtr = NULL;

  char com[MIN_LENGTH]; 
  char cho[MAX_LENGTH]; 

  while(strcmp(com, "end") != 0){
    printf("Command? ");
    scanf("%s", &com);

     if(strcmp(com, "ins") == 0){
       scanf("%s", &cho);
       ins(&startPtr, cho);
       printf("%s\n", cho);

        }

      else if(strcmp(com, "del") == 0){
    scanf("%s", &cho);
    if(del(&startPtr, cho)){
    }
    else{
      printf("%s not found.\n", cho);
    }
      }

      else if(strcmp(com, "prl") == 0){
    prl(startPtr);
       // printf("%s\n", cho);
    }

    else if(strlen(com) >= 4 || strlen(com) < 3){
    printf("You have entered an incorrect command.\n");
    }
  }
}


void ins(ListNode *ptr, char value){

  ListNode newPtr;
  ListNode prevPtr;
  ListNode currPtr;

  newPtr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(newPtr != NULL){
    newPtr->list = value;
    newPtr->next = NULL;

    prevPtr = NULL;
    currPtr = *ptr;

    while(currPtr != NULL && value > currPtr-> list){
      prevPtr = currPtr;
      currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }
    if(prevPtr == NULL){
      newPtr->next = *ptr;
      *ptr = newPtr;
    }
    else{ 
      prevPtr->next = newPtr;
      newPtr->next = currPtr;
    }
   }
    else{
      printf("No memory available\n");
    }
}
char del(ListNode *ptr, char value){
  ListNode prevPtr;
  ListNode currPtr;
  ListNode tempPtr;

  if(value == (*ptr)->list){
    tempPtr = *ptr;
    *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
    free(tempPtr);
    return value;
  }
  else{
    prevPtr = *ptr;
    currPtr = (*ptr)->next;

    while(currPtr != NULL && currPtr->list != value){
      prevPtr = currPtr;
      currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }

    if(currPtr != NULL){
      tempPtr = currPtr;
      prevPtr->next = currPtr->next;
      free(tempPtr);
      return value;
    }
  }
  return '\0';
}

char prl(ListNode currPtr){
  if(currPtr == NULL){
    printf("The List is Empty.\n");
  }else{
    while(currPtr != NULL){
      printf("%c\n", currPtr->list);
      currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your del() and ins() functions work with char instead of char*, also your Node struct.

Please note the changes I made in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN_LENGTH 4
#define MAX_LENGTH 11

struct node{
    char list[MAX_LENGTH];
    int count;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node *ListNode;

void ins(ListNode *ptr, char *value);
char* del(ListNode *ptr, char *value);
char prl(ListNode currPtr);


int main(void){

    ListNode startPtr = NULL;

    char com[MIN_LENGTH]; 
    char cho[MAX_LENGTH]; 

    while(strcmp(com, "end") != 0){
        printf("Command? ");
        scanf("%s", &com);

        if(strcmp(com, "ins") == 0){
            scanf("%s", &cho);
            ins(&startPtr, cho);
            printf("%s\n", cho);

        }

        else if(strcmp(com, "del") == 0){
            scanf("%s", &cho);
            if(del(&startPtr, cho)){
            }
            else{
                printf("%s not found.\n", cho);
            }
        }

        else if(strcmp(com, "prl") == 0){
            prl(startPtr);
            // printf("%s\n", cho);
        }

        else if(strlen(com) >= 4 || strlen(com) < 3){
            printf("You have entered an incorrect command.\n");
        }
    }
}


void ins(ListNode *ptr, char *value){

    ListNode newPtr;
    ListNode prevPtr;
    ListNode currPtr;

    newPtr = (ListNode) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(newPtr != NULL){
        memset(newPtr, 0, sizeof(Node));
        memcpy(newPtr->list, value, strlen(value));
        newPtr->next = NULL;

        prevPtr = NULL;
        currPtr = *ptr;

        while(currPtr != NULL && value > currPtr-> list){
            prevPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->next;
        }
        if(prevPtr == NULL){
            newPtr->next = *ptr;
            *ptr = newPtr;
        }
        else{ 
            prevPtr->next = newPtr;
            newPtr->next = currPtr;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("No memory available\n");
    }
}
char* del(ListNode *ptr, char *value){
    ListNode prevPtr;
    ListNode currPtr;
    ListNode tempPtr;

    if(0 == strcmp(value, (*ptr)->list)){
        tempPtr = *ptr;
        *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
        free(tempPtr);
        return value;
    }
    else{
        prevPtr = *ptr;
        currPtr = (*ptr)->next;

        while(currPtr != NULL && 0 != strcmp(value, currPtr->list)){
            prevPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->next;
        }

        if(currPtr != NULL){
            tempPtr = currPtr;
            prevPtr->next = currPtr->next;
            free(tempPtr);
            return value;
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}

char prl(ListNode currPtr){
    if(currPtr == NULL){
        printf("The List is Empty.\n");
    }else{
        while(currPtr != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", currPtr->list);
            currPtr = currPtr->next;
        }
    }
}
```